# QTreeView header display text

Tags: python, qt, treeview, pyside

I'm trying to display a simple list in a `QTreeView` and set the header display text:

```
+--------+
| Player |
+--------+
| Alice  |
| Bob    |
+--------+
```

However, I cannot get the header to display anything other than "1":

```
+--------+
| 1      |
+--------+
| Alice  |
| Bob    |
+--------+
```

I first tried a `QStringListModel` but that didn't change the header text.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

model = QStringListModel()
model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Player")
model.setStringList(["Alice", "Bob"])
```

I found [QTableView header difficulties](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-11587.html), so I tried using a `QStandardItemModel` like suggested but that still resulted in a header only displaying "1":

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

model = QStandardItemModel()
model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Player")
for player in ["Alice", "Bob"]:
    model.appendRow(QStandardItem(player))
```

I'd prefer to avoid defining my own model class if there's already a default Qt/PySide class that provides it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say what your problem is because there is enough information, but the following C++ code works

```
QStandardItemModel model;
model.setColumnCount (1);
model.setHeaderData (0, Qt::Horizontal, "Player");
QList<QStandardItem*> row;
row << new QStandardItem("Adam");
model.appendRow (row);
QTreeView view;
view.setModel (&model);
```

Try to check your code again.

Comment: Thanks, the `model.setColumnCount(1)` was what I was missing before `.setHeaderData()`.